# SQL Subquery Return NULL IN STATEMENT

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I use subquery in `IN` statement, but the result is null. My guess the problem is in data type but I can't solve this.

This is working:

```
select *
from qcpcs a with(NOLOCK)
where status = 0
  and active = 1  
  and Convert(varchar(8),assigned_to_dept_id) in (10000076, 10000049)
```

This is not working

```
select *
from qcpcs a with(NOLOCK)
where status = 0 
  and active = 1  
  and Convert(varchar(8),assigned_to_dept_id) in (select department_ids from users b
                                                  where b.[id] = 10000021)
```

This is the subquery's result:

[image]

Comment: Please, add text, not images.

Comment: please post query as text instead of images

Comment: Does your subquery return the correct IDs when you run it on it's own?

Comment: Post data set. B.id doesn't guarantee those assigned ids. We have no way of telling this currently

Comment: @jarlh I added text, sorry I am newbie here

Comment: @iamdave Yes, I show this in figure

Comment: @Baris  Your subquery is returning multiple IDs within the one field with a comma between them.  If you are using a subquery with the IN statement you need to have each ID on a separate row.

Comment: Solution: don't store data as comma separated items (in a column.) It will only cause you lots of problems. One value per column/row is the SQL way!

Comment: Slide side note. I notice you are using the NOLOCK hint. You might want to take a look at this article to understand everything that hint brings to the table. http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**As has been mentioned several times, the real solution here is to not store your values in comma separated lists.**

That aside, if you absolutely cannot change your database to take the above into account you can use the following, which is ***highly inefficient and ill-advised***:

```
select *
from qcpcs a with(NOLOCK)
where status = 0 
  and active = 1  
  and patindex('%' + Convert(varchar(8),assigned_to_dept_id) + '%'
              ,(select department_ids
                from users b
                where b.[id] = 10000021
               )
              ) > 0
```

Or you could use a string splitting function as described in great detail here:
http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/

**OR YOU COULD FIX YOUR DATABASE DESIGN.**

Comment: That is work. Thank you. I will consider your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM qcpcs a WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE STATUS = 0
    AND active = 1
    AND Convert(VARCHAR(8), assigned_to_dept_id) IN (
        SELECT convert(VARCHAR(8), department_ids) department_ids
        FROM users b
        WHERE b.[id] = 10000021
        )
```

Comment: This does not address the problem.  If you look a the data returned by the subquery in the screenshot, it is 2 IDs separated by a comma.